# Android - identify selected item from an autocompletetextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

i'm very new to the Android world: i have an autocompletetextview that allows me to choose from a list of cities.
How can i display the city i've selected from that list? (This list is quite big)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you look at the API DEMO project. There is a sample for the autocompletetextview